# Is bitwise aritmetic on pointers defined behavior?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, null-pointer

I'm learning about pointers. Given this code:

```
FILE* from = fopen("in.txt", "r");
FILE* to = fopen("out.txt", "w");
if (from == NULL || to == NULL)
{
    printf("failed to open files!\n");
    return;
}
```

Is changing the `if` condition to this valid (defined) behavior?

```
FILE* from = fopen("in.txt", "r");
FILE* to = fopen("out.txt", "w");
if ((from | to) == NULL)
{
    printf("failed to open files!\n");
    return;
}
```

Comment: I do not know whether this is well-formed in C, but in C++ it is ill-formed.  A pointer is not an integer.  Also, it's not nearly as clear as the explicit checks for NULL.  (Note also that your program is leaky:  if you successfully open one file but not the other, you'll leak the opened file handle.)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis about the leak. I am aware of that. This is just from a book. It teaches about cleaning up later. (Although I know about `fclose`)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis This question is about C. Not C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

First, it shouldn't compile, at least not if the compiler is standards-conformant.  Pointers are not valid operands for bitwise operators like `|` and `&`.

Second, even if your compiler lets you treat pointers as integers, you risk platform incompatibilities; there are C implementations where they're not at all interchangeable.  You might assume any such implementations would necessarily also be conformant, but assumptions are rarely safe...

Third, even assuming that ORing two pointers together works, and gets you something that you can compare with `NULL`, you've changed the sense of the test: `(from|to)` will only be `NULL` if *both* `fopen`s failed; if just one of them succeeded, the result will be nonzero and your code will fail.

Comment: So an `&` should have been used? Edited. But, my question still holds.

Comment: It's still implementation-defined.

Comment: It's not implementation-defined, it's simply not permitted by the standard.  No conformant C program is permitted to compute the logical OR of pointers.

Comment: @Cole - Using an `&` is even worse, because it tests if the values have any bits in common. The result is close to random.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: It is a constraint violation, meaning that an implementation that is fed a program containing such code must issue at least one diagnostic (a requirement that would be satisfied by a compiler that unconditionally output 'Warning: water is wet!") but would then have carte blanche to extend the language by processing the code in any manner that its users would find useful (or any other matter, for that matter).  If there exists any Conforming C Implementation that accepts some blob of text, that blob of text is *by definition* a Conforming C Program.

Comment: @supercat: Ok, then it would be a "conforming program" but still not a "correct" program.

Comment: @supercat: It's a bit silly, though... because conforming implementations are free to successfully translate invalid programs... which means that the term "conforming program" becomes kind of a useless word. For that reason, I don't think that reading of "conforming program" is correct.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The C89 Standard would have been soundly rejected if it categorized a substantial number of useful but non-portable programs as invalid, but it also would have been soundly rejected if it implied that implementations should be expected to regard such programs as valid.  The authors punted by defining a category of "Strictly Conforming" programs that would exclude everything that wouldn't be universally supportable (thus rejecting many popular programs, including all non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations), and a category of "Conforming C Programs" which...

Comment: ...avoids excluding any programs that, while non-portable, are nonetheless useful.  The Standard deliberately avoids passing any judgment regarding the validity of programs that need to accomplish anything not contemplated by the Standard; if you think that reading can't be right because it undermines the concept of a normative standard, google "C99 Rationale" and you'll see that the Standard was intended to waive jurisdiction over any contentious matters as "Quality of Implementation" issues.

Comment: @supercat: I don't see support for what you are claiming in the C99 rationale. There is, however, a part in the C standard where "shall" is explicitly spelled out as meaning a "requirement" in the C standard. That is how constraints are written.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The Standard explicitly states that violation of a constraint should have no more weight than the Standard's failure to specify the behavior of an action: the Standard would impose no requirements on how an implementation behave.  From the Rationale: "The goal of adopting this categorization is to allow a certain
variety among implementations which permits quality of implementation to be an active force in the marketplace as well as to allow certain popular extensions, without removing the cachet of conformance to the Standard."  Is there any reason to think that...

Comment: ...they did not intend the use of the phrase "popular extensions" to include situations where implementations would treats constructs that violate constraints the same way as they would be defined if the constraints were omitted from the Standard?  Also, "The goal is to give the programmer a fighting chance to make powerful C programs that are also highly portable, without seeming to demean perfectly useful C programs that happen not to be portable, thus the adverb strictly."

Comment: @supercat: I read that too, and I did not come to the same conclusion you did.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: What do you think was intended?  Bear in mind that essentially all non-trivial programs for freestanding implementations rely upon them behaving "in a documented manner characteristic of the environment" in some situations where the Standard imposes no requirements.

Comment: @supercat: My reading is that a conforming program may rely on unspecified, undefined, or implementation-defined behavior. It may exceed minimum implementation limits. However, it may not contain constraint violations.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: The Standard specifies that if a program contains a constraint violation, an implementation must issue at least one diagnostic (which the user may ignore), but may then process the program in whatever useful or useless fashion it sees fit; an implementation that unconditionally output a diagnostic would satisfy this requirement.  Many programs used things like zero-sized arrays to do things that were impossible before C99, as well as things that remain impossible even with C99, and had the Standard regarded such programs as "broken" it would almost certainly have been rejected.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Further, the term "runtime constraint" is only applicable in a few situations such as Annex K which impose requirements on how implementations behave if specified constraints are violated.  Otherwise, section 4 "Conformance" paragraph 2 explicitly says that if any other "shall" or "shall not" is violated, behavior is undefined, and there is no difference in emphasis between saying a program violates such a requirement and any other indication that behavior would be undefined.  In all cases, implementations may process the code usefully or uselessly as they see fit.

Comment: @supercat: I disagree with your premise that the standard would be rejected under those conditions, and I disagree with your reading of "conformant program". You seem to be rephrasing your argument in an attempt to convince me that you are correct. This would work if I didn't understand your argument in the first place, but I don't think that I misunderstand your argument at all.

Answer (score 5):

No.

For `T *x` and `T *y` in C, the expression `x|y` is meaningless, according to the standard.  It should not compile.  From n1256 §6.5.12 ¶2 "Bitwise inclusive OR operator":

> Each of the operands shall have integer type.

**This means that** `x|y` is an *error,* end of story.  The same applies to all other bitwise operators: `&` `|` `^` `~` `<<` `>>` are all *only* usable on integers (note that "integers" include characters and bools).

However, if you want to save effort typing, it is perfectly valid to use *logical* operators on pointers.

```
// x == NULL is exactly semantically equivalent to !x
// These two are exactly the same
if (x == NULL || y == NULL) ...
if (!x || !y) ...

// In a logical expression, x != NULL is exactly semantically equivalent to x
// These two are exactly the same
if (x != NULL && y != NULL) ...
if (x && y) ...
```

It is up to you whether you think `x == NULL` is better or `!x` is better.  You had better be able to read both, since both styles are common.

Answer (score 2):

Don't ever try to play games with bitwise operators and pointers.

If you are just looking for a more terse way to write the expression, this is a pretty common and idiomatic way to do this:

```
    FILE* from = fopen("in.txt", "r");
    FILE* to = fopen("out.txt", "w");
    if (!from || !to) // note the use of the ! operator
    {
        printf("failed to open files!\n");
        return;
    }
    ...
} /* end of function */
```

The `!` operator is a logical NOT operator.  Since the null pointer always has a value of 0, which is a "false" value, the expression `!from` means "true if `from` is a null pointer, otherwise false`.  It reads pretty well also: "if not from, or not to, then handle an error"

Likewise, people write code like `if (from)` to check if a pointer is non-NULL.

P.S. I know many people like to use expressions like `FILE*` when declaring pointers, but I dislike this form, because it is a lie.  When you declare `FILE *from` this means "the expression `*from` has type `FILE`".  It works to put the `*` right after the `FILE` but this makes it look like this means "the expression `from` has type pointer-to-`FILE`".  It doesn't, and here's an example:

```
FILE* from, to;
```

`from` has type "pointer-to-`FILE`".  What type is `to`?  Why it is plain old `FILE`, not any sort of pointer.  The expression you need to use, if you are declaring these on one line, is:

```
FILE *from, *to;
```

This means "the expression `*from` is type `FILE`, and the expression `*to` is type `FILE`."  And it looks like it, once you are used to this.

You could write this, but it's icky.

```
FILE* from, *to;
```

Yuck!

Comment: `Since the null pointer always has a value of 0` Thats where this comes from. Because `0 & <anything> == 0`.

Comment: Yes, but bitwise operators like `&` are not defined on pointer values in C, and logical operators like `!` are.  The C compiler won't let you play the bitwise tricks, and if it did, other programmers looking at your code might be confused.  The `!from` idiom is well-understood in the C community.  If you really wanted to do your bitwise AND trick, and you have C99 available, you could cast each pointer to type `intptr_t` and then bitwise AND the two.  Then every other programmer who looks at your code will shout "WTF!" when they see it, but if that's what you want, go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

`from` and `to` are pointers, you cannot do any bitwise operation on them. However, `<stdint.h>` provides `intptr_t` which is of integer type and is guaranteed to hold a pointer, so casting your pointers to them first would be valid. However, this is ugly, so I would stick with the more readable version.

Answer (score 0):

Bitwise operation are not allowed on pointers.

You should avoid such exercise.